# ColdFusion if statement with multiple conditions

Tags: coldfusion

I am working with some legacy code and I am stuck on evaluating a ColdFusion if statement with multiple conditions.  What I am looking to do is this:

```
<cfif condtion1 eq'yes'>
  Display admin text
 </cfif>

 <cfif condition2 eq'yes' && condition1 eq'no'>
  display non-admin text
  </cfif>

 <cfif condition2 eq'yes' && condition1 eq'yes'>
  display non-admin text
  </cfif>
```

If the first statement is true, it functions properly.
If the second statement is true, if functions properly.

If the third statement is true, it is displaying the text from the first statement when it should be displaying the text from the second statement.

Comment: No, && is perfectly fine.  @kidaiu - Okay...so what is your question? :)

Comment: @Leigh Yup. you're right. Some reason I had always used `AND` for tags and `&&` for script...not sure where I picked that up

Comment: @beloitdavisja - Well, it was not always supported ;-) The one I always mix up is trying to use `>` or `>=` in tags, when it only works in cfscript.

Comment: "If the third statement is true, it is displaying the text from the first statement when it should be displaying the text from the second statement."

if the third statement is true, then `condition1` is 'yes' and the first statement also true. If `condition1` is not 'yes' then the second statement would be false and would not show. Still confused to what you are asking?

Comment: In the application I am working with, a user can be admin, non-admin, or both.  If a user is an admin, statement1 is true: display some text.  If a user is non-admn: statement2 is true:display different text.  If a user is admin and non-admin, statement3 is true:  display the same text and statement 2.  Right now, if both conditions are true, it is display the text from statement 1 when it should be displaying the text from statement2.

Comment: (Edit) No, when a user is both, then [*both* statements 1 and 3 will be true](http://trycf.com/gist/f27c295756e502dd78f7/acf11?theme=monokai). Let me come at this from another angle. If a user is both an admin AND non admin, do you want to display a) admin text only b) non-admin text only or c) both admin AND non-admin text?

Comment: If a user is both, they should see non-admin text.

Comment: Are you saying option b) - *only* display the non-admin text when the user is both? http://trycf.com/gist/f19ffc61f4d9d7b5c2da/acf11?theme=monokai   (Sounds a little odd)

Answer (score 3):

To show "display admin text" only if `condition1` is met, you can go like this:

```
<cfset isAdmin  = condition1>
<cfset isUser   = condition2>

<cfif isAdmin and (not isUser)>
    Display admin text
<cfelse>
    display non-admin text
</cfif>
```

To clarify this:

```
<cfset isAdmin  = condition1>
<cfset isUser   = condition2>

<cfif isAdmin and isUser>
    I'm admin AND user.
<cfelseif isAdmin>
    I'm admin BUT NOT user.
<cfelseif isUser>
    I'm NOT admin, BUT user.
</cfif>
```

*Note: I declared "speaking" variables for better readability only.*

Comment: Nice explanation in the second section.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses on this.  I ended up combing through <cfdump> files and was able to isolate a variable that was null when condition one was met and not null when all others were met.  So I think I ended up with something close to what Alex was saying.  I also found the trycf.com site extremely helpful.  Being newish to the Stack community, not sure how the process works to show appreciation for the help on this.

Comment: @kidaiu - In general a) up vote any posts you found helpful b) If a post either answers your question completely, or provided most of the information leading you to an answer, check the green arrow next to it and mark it as the solution. c) In cases where you found your own solution - or your final code is *significantly* different than what was already posted in other answers - feel free to post your own answer. (That is allowed on S.O.) It not only helps the next guy, but folks can vote on it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned by Leigh in the comments, if condition1 eq 'yes' then both statements 1 and 3 are true.

Add a "condition2 neq 'yes'" to the first if statement if you want only one of those if block to be true in all cases.

Comment: Yep. Though to improve readability I would suggest changing the `eq 'yes'` and `neq 'yes'` stuff, to `isSomething` or `!isSomething` instead (and it could probably be expressed as two conditions rather than three).